# The credit plan at TidBit Computer Store

Tags: python

Program that takes the purchase price as input. The program should display a table, with appropriate headers, of a payment schedule for the lifetime of the loan.

I am new to python coding I have tried for hours and the resulted I posted is the best I can do. I have tried to use "break" but that result only gets me the first two months.

```
while ending> 0:
    Month+=1 
    payment = starting N * .05
    ending-=payment
    interest = (starting N * rate) / 12
    principal = payment - interest
    starting N = ending + payment
```

infinite loop

Comment: Try printing out your variables on every loop and see if they match what you expect... you'll likely find the issue

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are deleting from `ending` a value (`payment`) that becomes quickly really small at each iteration (by a factor of 1/20 = 0.05).

Fixing:

```
ending = 1000
N = ending
```

as start values, you get:

```
while ending> 0:
    Month+=1 
    payment = N * .05
    ending-=payment
    interest = (starting N * rate) / 12 # don't think about this value now 
    principal = payment - interest # don't think about this value now 
    N = ending + payment # N becomes the previous ending, without subtracting payment
    print("Ending: ", ending, "Payment:", payment)




# Ending:  4e-323 Payment: 0.0
# Ending:  4e-323 Payment: 0.0
# Ending:  4e-323 Payment: 0.0
...
```

Basically, the amount that you pay at the end becomes so small that the values doesn't go under `4e-323`, which is really near to 0.

And because `4e-323 * 0.05` is basically 0 in python you get a value that is forever near to 0 without becoming smaller.

```
payment = 4e-323 * 0.05 # 0
ending -= payment # 4e-323 - 0 = 4e-323
```

One solution could be to set the condition in the while statement as such:

```
while ending > 0.00000001 :
     ...
```